# "No input file specified" error in Sagepay integration kit

Tags: php, .htaccess, opayo

I'm new to Sagepay and I'm trying to set up a test site to get my head round it but I keep coming up on a `No input file specified` error when I try and access a demo page.

The test files (http://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/find-an-integration-document/form-integration) have been placed here:

```
www.mydomain.com/dev/sagepaytest/
```

And an example of a page I can't access would be

```
www.mydomain.com/dev/sagepaytest/demo/form
```

The contents of my .htaccess file is

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(assets).* $0 [L]

RewriteRule ^(app|bootstrap|config|cron|error|messages)\.php$ - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^(controller|helper|model|views) - [F,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Which version of PHP are you using? If it is the 'FastCGI' version you could try switching to 'stable' to see whether that resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I spent 48 hours to fix that, looks I'm step away from finish this integration...

In `demo/app.php` on line 40 change `PATH_INFO` for `QUERY_STRING`  (same as `ORIG_PATH_INFO` for `ORIG_QUERY_STRING`)

and

In `.htaccess` last RewriteRule must be like this `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]`

Due to I'm forgot my livesagepay account details I cannot check is it works till the end, before I will get new password. But at least now I can see Form integration page